# Wagtail panel for self-referential many to many relationships with a through model

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I am busy making something like a knowledge graph in wagtail.

`CurriculumContentItem` is a node on that graph.  It has a many-to-many relationship with itself, and the through model has important fields.

I'm struggling to get this to be usable in the admin page. Please see the inline comments:

```
class ContentItemOrder(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        "CurriculumContentItem", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="pre_ordered_content"
    )
    pre = models.ForeignKey(
        "CurriculumContentItem", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="post_ordered_content"
    )
    hard_requirement = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class CurriculumContentItem(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    prerequisites = models.ManyToManyField(
        "CurriculumContentItem",
        related_name="unlocks",
        through="ContentItemOrder",
        symmetrical=False,
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        # FieldPanel("prerequisites") 
        # FieldPanel just lets me select CurriculumContentItems, but I need to access fields in the through model

        # InlinePanel("prerequisites"), 
        # This causes a recursion error

        FieldPanel('body', classname="full collapsible"),
    ]
```

If I wanted to do this in the normal Django admin I would make use of an inlines to specify prerequisites. Something like:

```
class ContentItemOrderPostAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.ContentItem.prerequisites.through
    fk_name = "post"

class ContentItemOrderPreAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.ContentItem.unlocks.through
    fk_name = "pre"
```

Is there a similar mechanism in Wagtail?

It looks like I need to create a custom Panel for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

1. Make the through model inherit from Orderable
2. Make use of `ParentalKey` instead of `ForeignKey`
3. Use InlinePanel referring to the related names of the fields in the through models

```
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable


class ContentItemOrder(Orderable):   ### 1
    post = ParentalKey(   ### 2
        "CurriculumContentItem", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="pre_ordered_content"
    )
    pre = ParentalKey(   ### 2
        "CurriculumContentItem", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="post_ordered_content"
    )
    hard_requirement = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('pre'),
        PageChooserPanel('post'),
        FieldPanel('hard_requirement'),
    ]


class CurriculumContentItem(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    prerequisites = models.ManyToManyField(
        "CurriculumContentItem",
        related_name="unlocks",
        through="ContentItemOrder",
        symmetrical=False,
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel('pre_ordered_content', label="prerequisites"),  ### 3
        InlinePanel('post_ordered_content', label="unlocks"),       ### 3

        FieldPanel('body', classname="full collapsible"),
    ]
```

I was worried that there would be 2 PageChooser fields available per inline but wagtail is clever (and magical) enough that it just draws the one we need

Comment: I should note that having two ParentalKeys on one model is not "officially" valid. It's likely to have weird results if you save the page on one side as a draft and then make edits on the other side, causing them to get out of sync... if you always publish pages straight away you're probably fine, though.

Comment: @gasman:  Thanks, that's good to know. Is that why you have a Foreign Key and a Parental key in your answer?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest constructing an InlinePanel pointing to your 'through' model, which means that you're working with a one-to-many relation rather than many-to-many:

```
class ContentItemOrder(models.Model):
    post = ParentalKey(
        "CurriculumContentItem", related_name="pre_ordered_content"
    )
    pre = models.ForeignKey(
        "CurriculumContentItem", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="post_ordered_content"
    )
    hard_requirement = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('pre'),
        FieldPanel('hard_requirement')
    ]


class CurriculumContentItem(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel("pre_ordered_content"), 

        FieldPanel('body', classname="full collapsible"),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks man, but I figured it out. My answer works. Yours is still missing stuff. I'm going to mark mine as correct.